# lightning/navigation in communities lwc

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightningnavigation

How to navigate to a standard record page in Communities after a record is created.

Following i tried it's not navigating though.

```
  this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
                type: 'standard__recordPage',
                attributes: {
                    recordId: event.detail.id,
                    objectApiName: 'Case',
                    actionName: 'view'
                },
            });
```

Comment: There can be three issues:
1) Have you imported and extended "NavigationMixin" module?
2) Do you have access to the Case?
3) Are you getting event.detail.id?

Comment: yes yes yes yes

Comment: If you are using a modal for creating a case record then you must write the code for navigating first and then close the modal (or no need to close the modal)

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use type: 'comm__namedPage' if you're in a community

Answer (score 0):

Your code will work provided `event.detail.id` exists and that the component both imports the NavigationMixin and extends NavigationMixin.

```js
import { NavigationMixin } from 'lightning/navigation';

export default class MyComponent extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {

    navigate(event) {
        this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
            type: 'standard__recordPage',
            attributes: {
                recordId: event.detail.id,
                objectApiName: 'Case',
                actionName: 'view'
            },
        });
    }

}
```